# Error Duplicate Info on Insert ASPNET CORE

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I add an employee, I ask for the data of the company, adding the next employee asks me again the data of the company and generates duplicate records. If the two employees are from the same company as it should be my validation so that I do not re-register the company?

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(45)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BussinesName { get; set; }

    public string WebAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

POST CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Employee data)
    {
        //Validamos
        if(ModelState.IsValid){
            //Agregamos registro
            _context.Employee.Add(data); 
            return Ok(_context.SaveChanges());
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

The response to missing company data is:

```
{
  "Person": [
    "The Person field is required."
 ],
  "Company.Code": [
  "The Code field is required."
 ],
   "Company.Name": [
   "The Name field is required."
 ]
 }
```

Company Details

```
{
"Person": {
  "lastNamePat": "Juan",
  "lastNameMat": null,
  "firstName": "Lopez"
},
 "Company" :{
    "Code": "XXX",
    "Name": "test"
}
```

}

Company Table
[image: Database Duplicate Info]

How to validate not duplicate information?

Comment: You don't appear to have a foreign key between your `Employee` and `Company` entities.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. Basically you need to set "Company" to null if already exists.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (data != null && data.Company != null)
                {
                    if (_context.Employee.Company.Any(x => x.Code == data.Company.Code))
                    {
                        data.Company = null;
                        _context.Employee.Add(data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _context.Employee.Add(data);
                    }
                }

                return Ok(_context.SaveChanges());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Comment: But when I define the company as null, I do not refer to the company for that employee, I would need to save the information, the employee belongs to that company but not to add the company again, which would double

Comment: So assign existing company instead of null

Answer (score 0):

You  can  use Abstract validator.
Model Is valid state is configured  your validation rule.
Example

```
RuleFor(c => c.ModuleId)
   .NotEmpty()
   .WithMessage("Module id is required.")
   .Must(BeAnExistingModule)
   .WithMessage("Module does not exist.");

private bool BeAnExistingModule(AddVersion cmd, Guid moduleId)
{
    return _moduleRules.DoesModuleExist(cmd.SiteId, moduleId);
}
```